# Resta de subconsultas, es posible?

Tags: sql

Buen día, espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente:
Intento hacer una consulta en la cual quiero que me regrese el complemento de una consulta anterior, de momento solo pude sacarlo por porcentaje haciendo una resta de consultas, pero me gustaría saber si hay forma de ver todos los valores que son resultado de esa resta

```
SELECT((
SELECT COUNT(*)
From dbo.SurveyTable
WHERE Q9_Jupyter=1 AND Q9_Rstudio>=0 AND Q9_Visual_Studio_Code=0 AND Q9_Visual_Studio>=0 AND 
Q9_PyCharm>=0 AND Q9_Spyder>=0 AND Q9_Notepad>=0 AND Q9_Sublime_Text>=0 AND Q9_VimEmacs>=0
AND Q9_MATLAB>=0 AND Q9_None>=0 AND Q9_Other>=0)-
(SELECT COUNT(*)
From dbo.SurveyTable
WHERE Q9_Jupyter = 1 AND Q9_Rstudio=0 AND Q9_Visual_Studio_Code=0 AND Q9_Visual_Studio=0 AND 
Q9_PyCharm=0 AND Q9_Spyder=0 AND Q9_Notepad=0 AND Q9_Sublime_Text=0 AND Q9_VimEmacs=0
AND Q9_MATLAB=0 AND Q9_None=0 AND Q9_Other=0)) AS Jupyter_SinVSC
```

En el código únicamente me esta regresando la resta de los COUNT, pero me gustaría ver cuales son los datos resultantes de esa resta.
Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Comment: Cual es la `primary key` de `SurveyTable` ? Que motor de base de datos es?

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, ya lo resolví con la función EXCEPT. Esta base no tenia una ID como tal, la utilice para poder acomodarla y realizar consultas rápidas. Muchas gracias, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para empezar, puedes optimizar tu consulta para hacer una sola lectura de la tabla.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
     - COUNT( CASE WHEN Q9_Rstudio = 0
                    AND Q9_Visual_Studio = 0
                    AND Q9_PyCharm = 0
                    AND Q9_Spyder = 0
                    AND Q9_Notepad = 0
                    AND Q9_Sublime_Text = 0
                    AND Q9_VimEmacs = 0
                    AND Q9_MATLAB = 0
                    AND Q9_None = 0
                    AND Q9_Other = 0
                THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM dbo.SurveyTable
WHERE Q9_Jupyter = 1
AND Q9_Rstudio >= 0
AND Q9_Visual_Studio_Code = 0
AND Q9_Visual_Studio >= 0
AND Q9_PyCharm >= 0
AND Q9_Spyder >= 0
AND Q9_Notepad >= 0
AND Q9_Sublime_Text >= 0
AND Q9_VimEmacs >= 0
AND Q9_MATLAB >= 0
AND Q9_None >= 0
AND Q9_Other >= 0;
```

Con eso, te puedes dar una idea de como obtener el detalle de cuales se cuentan y cuales no. Solo tienes que eliminar las funciones de agregado.

```
SELECT *, 
     CASE WHEN Q9_Rstudio = 0
            AND Q9_Visual_Studio = 0
            AND Q9_PyCharm = 0
            AND Q9_Spyder = 0
            AND Q9_Notepad = 0
            AND Q9_Sublime_Text = 0
            AND Q9_VimEmacs = 0
            AND Q9_MATLAB = 0
            AND Q9_None = 0
            AND Q9_Other = 0
        THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS SeCuenta --Observa que se invierte la condición
FROM dbo.SurveyTable
WHERE Q9_Jupyter = 1
AND Q9_Rstudio >= 0
AND Q9_Visual_Studio_Code = 0
AND Q9_Visual_Studio >= 0
AND Q9_PyCharm >= 0
AND Q9_Spyder >= 0
AND Q9_Notepad >= 0
AND Q9_Sublime_Text >= 0
AND Q9_VimEmacs >= 0
AND Q9_MATLAB >= 0
AND Q9_None >= 0
AND Q9_Other >= 0;
```